# To Use or not to user Areas in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a project in `ASP.MVC5` and Im in the middle to decide if I use `Areas` or not.

The project will have 3 types of applications inside:

- Customer users
- Interal users
- Support users

The hole application will share the login page, and depending on the user type Im planning to redirect to the right `Area`.

So I was thinking on the above idea or just use the default structure and then have:

- Views/Customer/and here my views
- Views/Internal/and here my views
- Views/Support/and here my views

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have similar controllers and models and views for each different "module" (Customer, Internal, Support) then areas would help organize it. For example, if your customer is going to have OrdersController (Edit, Display, Create etc.) and the corresponding models and views and your Support will also have similar controllers, models and views then it is worth creating areas. That way your routes will look like this:

```
~/customer/orders/1/edit

~/customer/orders/create

~/support/orders/1/edit

~/support/orders/create
```

But if that is not the case, then it is not worth it because areas do tend to make things a little more complicated.

I would start with the simple, no areas, structure firstly. If you see the need for areas then create them.